# Extract data from open street map databases

Tags: openstreetmap

Open street map has different downloadable data like `.osm.pbf` and `.osm.bz`

How can I extract data from open street map databases? for instance I want to extract all banks in a country, administration area, ...

Is there any desktop application that can help me to open/edit/export street map databases

Comment: See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats#Filter_for_specific_tags, especially osmium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to set up an Overpass API server (or if your query volume is low to just use one of the public instances).

Or you could use osm2pgsql to import all data into a PostGIS database, and then use SQL to perform your queries.

Or last not least you could process the raw osm data in a streaming fashion, without having to set up a database at all, using the Osmium/pyOsmium libraries ...

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API

https://osm2pgsql.org/

https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/